# How to slice df by col name when some of the columns are of datetime.time type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, subset

Given a df of this type:

```
A = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 5, 2, 8, 2], [2, 4, 4, 20, 2], [3, 3, 1, 20, 2], [4, 2, 2, 1, 0], [5, 1, 4, -5, -4], 
    [1, 5, 2, 2, -20], [2, 4, 4, 3, 0], [3, 3, 1, -1, -1], [4, 2, 2, 0, 0], [5, 1, 4, 20, -2]],
    columns=[datetime.time(8, 20), datetime.time(8, 30), '0 009', 'name', datetime.time(9, 0)],
    index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
)
```

Im trying to select some columns by name like:

```
b = A[[col for col in A if "0 " in col or "name" in col]]
```

However, I got an error:

> TypeError: argument of type 'datetime.time' is not iterable

How can I slice the df by column name when some of the columns are of `datetime.time` type?

An alternative path is to select first the columns which name is a string and then I can use the procedure I intended originally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas offers a method called `filter` which selects specific columns based on their name. You can select these columns in different ways with regex being one of them. Looking at the source code, the columns are converted to strings when using `like` or `regex` but not `items` so this should work for datetime column names.

```
A.filter(regex='0 |name')

    0 009  name
1       2     8
2       4    20
3       1    20
4       2     1
5       4    -5
6       2     2
7       4     3
8       1    -1
9       2     0
10      4    20
```